# Continue while loop after an exit code 255 is set in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop, exit

Inside a while loop I make a call to a library called HTML2PDF and if there is malformed HTML an exit code of 255 happens.  I am trying to catch these codes, alert the user, then continue the while loop but it keeps on exiting.

Here are the basics of the code.

```
while(($result = sqlFetchArray($res))){
....
     $content = getContent();
     try {

        $success =  $pdf->writeHTML($content, false);

             } catch (Exception $e){


                  echo "PDF generation failed for: $pid \n";
                  continue;

         }

echo "PDF gen successful here";

} 

//more code to follow.
```

The issue is that writeHTML($content, false) sends and exit code of 255 which then kills my loop.  I am expected to run this loop about 200 times but it stops at 8.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.  Note:  When I use the try catch I get an exit status of 0.  I don't want the while loop to stop working.

Comment: If you mean that the library calls `exit()` with code 255, there is unfortunately nothing you can do. The script just ends there.

Comment: Errorlevel 255 usually means that error in script occured - are there any error messages from PHP? Maybe they should be enabled in php.ini or by error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); After adding try-catch is message "PDF generation failed for" printed?